# Add HTML with Vanilla Javascript if element doesn't exists in DOM

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Im trying to add an element to the DOM, but want to add it only if the element doesn't exist. Since I will use the function in a ajax call as well, it would repeat itself, hence I need to check if the element already exists.

With jQuery this is easy:

```
if( jQuery(".class").length == 0){
jQuery("<div class='new_div'></div>").appendTo(".toolbar-sorter");
}
```

How to I do the same check with vanilla JS? Current code:

```
const element = document.querySelector(".toolbar-sorter")
element.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<div class='new_div'></div>");
```

Comment: It's pointless to post jQ/JS DOM manipulations without the HTML.

Comment: @secan I update the question. The function will run on ajaxComplete as well, so it will duplicate if I dont have a check. The jQuery function works well, but I want it in Vanilla JS.

Comment: There is a vanilla-javascript version on this existing question: [Is there an exists in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
const element = document.querySelector(".toolbar-sorter")

if (document.querySelectorAll(".class").length == 0) {
  element.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<div class='new_div'></div>")
}
```

**Edit:** so apparently jQuerys `appendTo` function iterates all elements with the specific selector and appends to each of them (I did not know this, thanks @pilchard).

So a more "correct" conversion could be:

```js
if (document.querySelectorAll(".class").length == 0) {
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".toolbar-sorter")

  elements.forEach(element => {
    element.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<div class='new_div'></div>")
  })
}
```

Comment: [`appendTo`](https://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) inserts into every matched element, so as @Teemu commented, you would need to `querySelectorAll(".toolbar-sorter")` and iterate the nodeList inserting into each matched element.

Comment: You can shorten `document.querySelectorAll(".class").length == 0` to `!document.querySelector(".class")`. Also you could probably skip the lookup of `elements` if it already exists.

Comment: I know @Lain, just wanted to write code that more resembled the jQuery code he posted.

Comment: Alright, makes sense.

Comment: But you are right about the elements lookup. Should have propably been moved inside the if statement, I'll edit.